# Restore from a windows 10 File History backup to a new computer?

Tags: windows-10, restore, file-history

Updated 27.03.17

This question is very similar to [How do you restore from a File History backup to a new computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/659953/how-do-you-restore-from-a-file-history-backup-to-a-new-computer) but up to now I didn't succeed with the prescriptions given there because there are some differences in the consiguration.

I repeat the main question: "my windows-10 computer died, but I have a File History backup from it. How do I transfer the data from there to my new windows-10 computer? I can't just copy it because all the file names are appended with the date of the latest version."

Now to my situation:

1) The structures of source and destination are different: the backup (about 700 GB) was made on a computer with one drive (c:) whereas the new PC has an SSD (c:) (200 GB) as a system drive, and the data should go to drive d: (2 TB).
This should be no problem as it is described in the reference.

2) I followed the prescription and tried to restore the (small) Folder "Contacts". But the result was an empty folder Contacts on d:
This failure mght be due to the structure I'll show in 3)

3) Different user names
I have different user names in the old and the new PC.
This shows up in the folder struture on the backup drive. 
Notice that the new structure was generated (unintended) after activating FileHistory.

> FileHistory
>   |- Lotti (the new struture), details see below
>   |- weh (the old structure), details see below
>
> |- weh (the old structure)
>   |---ALBERT
>   |----- configuration
>   |----- data
>   |------- $OF
>   |------- C
>   |--------- users
>   |----------- Public
>   |----------- weh
>   |------------- contacts
>   |------------- Desktop
>   |------------- Documents
>   ...
>   |------------- Videos
>
> |- Lotti (the new structure) <- ### difference ###
>   |---DESKTOP-4U2ERQ <- ### difference ###
>   |----- configuration
>   |----- data
>   |------- $OF
>   |------- C
>   |--------- users
>   |----------- Public (not created)
>   |----------- Lotti <- ### difference ###
>   |------------- Contacts
>   |------------- Desktop
>   |------------- Documents
>   ...
>   |------------- Videos

Notice that the folders of the new structure already contain some data due to the installations on c:

Question: what do I have to do to make it work (see 2)?

4) The libraries on the new PC currently point to c: However I want to place my data on d:

Question: I think I should change the links under the libraries, but do I do this before or after a (hopefully) succesful restore to d:?

Comment: File History didnnot chnage between Windows 8 and Windows 10, so the solution, is the same.  There is even a Windows 10 answer to your linked question.  So what's your question, and how does the detailed answer to the question you linked to, not answer your question?

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for providing part of the answer in your comment stating that nothing has changed between W8 and W10. The last paragraph of my question is still open. Maybe someone can help.

Comment: If you can't navigate the Windows UI in German change it to a language you can navigate.  The linked question has an answer which seems to tell you precisely what to click.

Comment: I have found the German commands, and I have tried to restore the (small) Folder Contacts but the contact folder shown in the selected new location is empty. The problem seems t be that the old user was different from the new one, and I can't select the old user. On my backup drive the Folder File History has now this structure >olduser/(my old data), >newuser/(a few new data coming from switching on File History). So I am stuck here.

Comment: @Ramhound  I have updated my question providing more details which hopefully transform my question into a reasonable one. I am a newby to FileHistory, I have saved data since Jan. but there was no need  to restore anything - until, unfortunately my old PC crashed some days ago.